# align the thumbnails differently in mobile as the bootstrap grid says?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap, alignment, thumbnails

[image: this is how it looks like if i have it xs 12]All is fine until it gets mobile.

The bootstrap grid I am using currantly does allign 2 images if mobile.

But I'd prefer it to be only one image using the whole screensize.

The grid is perfect for everything else as I dont want it to be too much free space hanging around..

Even for mobile it would be perfect, but if I look the image mobile, they all look sooo small.

So I want them to be only one image at a time if the mobile is in portrait mode and 2 img if the mobile is horizontal.

Does anybody have a solution for me???

Here's my code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
```

```
    <meta content="" name="keywords">
    <meta content="" name="description">        
    <meta content="index,follow" name="robots">
    <meta content="" name="author">
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html;charset=utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">

    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/bootstrap.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/navbar-marquee-grey.css" />
    <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/zeichnungen.css" />
    <link href="css/nivo-lightbox.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <link href="themes/default/default.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">

</head>

<body>

    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <!-- JS FILES -->
    <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.7.2/jquery.min.js"></script>
    <script src="js/bootstrap.js"></script>
    <script src="js/navbar.js"></script>
    <!-- Include all compiled plugins (below), or include individual files as needed -->
    <script src="js/custom.js"></script>
    <script src="js/nivo-lightbox.js"></script>

    <marquee scrollamount="1" scrolldelay="1"> nächste Ausstellung am...</marquee>
<!--NAVBAR-->
    <nav class="navbar navbar-inverse navbar-fixed-bottom" role="navigation">
      <div class="container-fluid">
        <!-- Brand and toggle get grouped for better mobile display -->
        <div class="navbar-header">
          <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
            <span class="sr-only">Toggle navigation</span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
            <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          </button>
          <li ><a class="navbar-brand" href="D-1-Home.html"><img src="Bilder/2.png" type="picture/png" style="max-height:45px;margin-top:-10px"/></a></li>
        </div>

        <!-- Collect the nav links, forms, and other content for toggling -->
        <div class="collapse navbar-collapse" id="bs-example-navbar-collapse-1">
          <ul id="menu" class="nav custom-menu nav-justified">


            <li><a href="D-2-Figuren.html">Figuren</a></li>
            <li class="active"><a href="D-3-Zeichnungen.html">Zeichnungen</a></li> 
            <li><a href="D-4-Vita.html">Vita</a></li>
            <li><a href="D-5-News.html">Aktuelles</a></li>
            <li class="dropdown">
              <a href="#" class="dropdown-toggle" data-toggle="dropdown">Kontakt und Impressum<b class="caret"></b></a>
              <ul class="dropdown-menu">
                <li><a href="D-6-1-Kontact.html">Kontakt</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><a href="D-6-2-WebFoto.html">Webseitengestaltung,<br> Foto und Film</a></li>
                <li class="divider"></li>
                <li><p>Copyright 2014</p></li>
              </ul>
            </li>
            <li><a href="E-1-Home.html">English</a></li>
          </ul>
        </div><!-- /.navbar-collapse -->
      </div><!-- /.container-fluid -->
    </nav>
    <!--NAVBAR ENDE-->

    <div class="container"data-toggle="modal" data-target="#myModal">
      <div class="row">
        <h3 style="text-align:center">
            Zeichnungen
            <small>Werkauswahl</small>
        </h3>
        <div class="row">
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Johannes von Gott (1997) - Bleistift - 26 x 18 cm"                        href="Zeichnungen/k-88.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="0"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive active" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-88.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Pietà (1995) - Bleistift - 30 x 20 cm"                                    href="Zeichnungen/k-89.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="1"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-89.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Akt, nachdenklich (2004) - Aquarell - 30 x 21 cm"                         href="Zeichnungen/k-179.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="2"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-179.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="the age of bronze, Skizze, Oberkörper (1996) - Bleistift - 24 x 18 cm"    href="Zeichnungen/k-113.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="3"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-113.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Königin (2002) - Farbstift, Aquarell - 31 x 22 cm"                        href="Zeichnungen/k-124.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="4"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive active" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-124.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Ricordo di Napoli (1997) - Tusche - 33 x 22 cm"                           href="Zeichnungen/k-101.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="5"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-101.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Jüngling, Kopf (1999) - Bleistift - 28 x 22 cm"                           href="Zeichnungen/k-120.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="6"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-120.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Anne (1991) - Bleistift - 15 x 11 cm"                                     href="Zeichnungen/k-97.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="7"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-97.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Egon Schiele (2007) - Bleistift, Aquarell - 20 x 28 cm"                   href="Zeichnungen/k-205.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="8"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-205.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Rückenakt in Gelb (2007) - Bleistift, Aquarell - 30 x 21 cm"              href="Zeichnungen/k-103.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="9"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-103.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Akt in Rosa (2004) - Bleistift, Aquarell - 32 x 24 cm"                    href="Zeichnungen/k-105.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="10"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-105.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Greis, nach Tiepolo 2 (1996)- Bleistift - 23 x 19 cm"                     href="Zeichnungen/k-99.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="11"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-99.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Ester, Portait (2006)- Aquarell - 28 x 22 cm"                             href="Zeichnungen/k-107.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="12"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-107.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Ravello, Aussicht nach Osten (2006) - Aquarell - 32 x 24 cm"          href="Zeichnungen/k-137.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="13"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-137.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Il Terrazzo dell'infinito (2006) - Tusche, Aquarell - 32 x 24 cm"     href="Zeichnungen/k-126.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="14"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-126.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Akt knieend (2002) - Bleistift, Aquarell - 30 x 40 cm"                    href="Zeichnungen/k-132.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="15"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-132.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Brasilianerin als Akt, liegend (2003) - Tusche, Aquarell - 18 x 20 cm"    href="Zeichnungen/k-142.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="16"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-142.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Cefoulú (2007) - Aquarell - 29 x 40 cm"                                   href="Zeichnungen/k-108.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="17"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-108.jpg"></a></div>
            <div class="col-lg-3 col-sm-4 col-xs-6"><a title="Fohlen (1997) - Bleistift - 12 x 16 cm"                                   href="Zeichnungen/k-98.jpg"data-lightbox-gallery="myGallery" data-slide-to="18"><img class="thumbnail img-responsive" src="Zeichnungen/k-k-98.jpg"></a></div>





        </div>
      </div>
    </div>


    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').nivoLightbox();
    });
    </script>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function(){
    $('a').nivoLightbox({
    effect: 'fade', // The effect to use when showing the lightbox
    theme: 'default', // The lightbox theme to use
    keyboardNav: true, // Enable/Disable keyboard navigation (left/right/escape)
    onInit: function(){}, // Callback when lightbox has loaded
    beforeShowLightbox: function(){}, // Callback before the lightbox is shown
    afterShowLightbox: function(lightbox){}, // Callback after the lightbox is shown
    beforeHideLightbox: function(){}, // Callback before the lightbox is hidden
    afterHideLightbox: function(){}, // Callback after the lightbox is hidden
    onPrev: function(element){}, // Callback when the lightbox gallery goes to previous item
    onNext: function(element){}, // Callback when the lightbox gallery goes to next item
    errorMessage: 'The requested content cannot be loaded. Please try again later.' // Error message when content can't be loaded});
    });
    </script>
```

further I m using

```
    body {
        background-color: #f1f1f1 !important;
    }
    .thumbnail {

        padding: 0px;
        box-shadow: 0px 3px 7px #d1d2d1;
    }


    .nivo-lightbox-wrap  {
        position: absolute;
        top: 5% !important;
        bottom: 7%!important;
        left: 10%;
        right: 10%;
    }
    .nivo-lightbox-theme-default .nivo-lightbox-title {
        background: none repeat scroll 0 0 transparent!important;
        border-radius: 30px;
        color: #fff;
        font: 14px/20px 'Helvetica Neue',Helvetica,Arial,sans-serif;
        padding: 7px 15px;
    }
```

And I'm using nivo and bootstrap css..

Comment: Should be `col-xs-12` in portrait mode. Bootstrap doesn't really have "in-between" sizes for landscape. You'd have to write in your own class/media query for that.

Comment: You should be using `col-xs-12` instead of `col-xs-6`. 12/12 = 100%, 6/12 = 50%.

Comment: yes... but if I do this the img aligns stubidly at the left and I cant center it so it looks better. the best would be if it would be 100% height in xs devices and centered, but i really dont know how to do that.. (tried margin 0 auto. wont work)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

ok I found the solution .. thx for helping.. :) 
It was sooo easy just put it class="thumbnail img-responsive **center-block**"
now i just need to fiddle out why the img is not bigger, but i guess that will just take a few min.. :)

[image]

sooo happy... :D